# Adding polygons from an existing layer to a new layer (shapefile)?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, polygon, copy, parcel

I have an existing shapefile that contains parcel data.  I would like to add some of the existing parcels to a new shapefile.  I am using ArcMap 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a new shapefile, containing just some of the existing parcels, but no others, simply query for, or select the ones you want, then right-click on the layer select Data, then Export Data.  If you have an existing shapefile follow the advise of @Maksim

Answer (score 1):

Either make a selection of the polygons you need, right click, copy, then paste into your new shapefile in the interactive window.

Or, use append, to add the selected polygons to a shapefile of your choosing.

Comment: where do i find the append function?

Comment: in the Data Management toolbox, or the geoprocessing drop-down menu.